# Magento upgrade PEAR error

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I was following the instructions at http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/ when i was up to the command

```
./pear upgrade -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest-stable
```

and am getting the error

> WARNING: channel "connect.magentocommerce.com/core" has updated its
>   protocols, use "channel-update connect.magentocommerce.com/core" to
>   update

I have searched the web and can't find anything that refers to this.

I have tried

```
./pear upgrade -f channel-update connect.magentocommerce.com/core
```

but that does not work.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: As a general comment, "that does not work" isn't very helpful. If it doesn't work, what *does* it do?

Answer (score 4):

Just had this problem, you need to run:

```
./pear channel-update connect.magentocommerce.com/core
```

after that completes you should now be able to run:

```
./pear upgrade -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with giving it a go using the GUI - Magento Connect Manager in Admin->System?

Assuming you have everything backed up, you can also zap public_html and reinstall 1.4 - makes no odds doing it that way as you will have lots to update including your theme, with reinstall you will keep your products, customers and orders.