# Magento Upgrade 1.3 1.4 Pear Error Invalid Argument foreach

Tags: magento, pear, magento-1.3

Hello I am trying to upgrade Magento 1.3 to 1.4. using this guide http://astrio.net/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/

I tried the command ./pear upgrade -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest-stable

I got the error

Notice: Array to string conversion in PEAR/REST/10.php on line 85
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/www/sss/staging.mysite.net/public/downloader/pearlib/php/PEAR/REST/10.php on line 85

So I tried [Magento upgrade PEAR error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382465/magento-upgrade-pear-error) ( specifically this command ./pear channel-update connect.magentocommerce.com/core ) .. but that gives me the error:

Updating channel "connect.magentocommerce.com/core"
Channel "connect.magentocommerce.com/core" is not responding over http://, failed with message: File http://connect.magentocommerce.com:80/core/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
)
Trying channel "connect.magentocommerce.com/core" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "connect.magentocommerce.com/core" (File https://connect.magentocommerce.com:443/core/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
))

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You waited a bit too long to upgrade if you want to use Magento Connect to do it.

In order to upgrade 1.4 to a later version using Magento Connect requires you to upgrade to the 1.5 PEAR Connect package which switches from using `./pear` to `./mage`. There is no equivalent to doing this upgrade for 1.3 to use Connect to upgrade to 1.4.

You will need to manually download and apply the Magento 1.4 upgrade by downloading the full package from [the Magento CE Download page under the Release Archives](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/) for the version of 1.4 you wish to upgrade to.

Of course, test it hard on a staging server as you will find that there will be template issues, database upgrade issues, etc.